# Opencv Mat multiplication by constant operation protected of overflow?

Tags: opencv, integer-overflow

Is Opencv Mat multiplication by constant operation protected of overflow?

```
Mat m(12,14,CV_8UC1);
float C=12.01;
//...do something with m
m= m*C;
```

i.e. can be result of multiplication be more than 255?

Also I can't find operator * definition in opencv [github repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image is of type `CV_8UC1`, the result will always be in [0,255].

The actual operation is in `matop.cpp`:

```
MatExpr operator * (const Mat& a, double s)
{
    MatExpr e;
    MatOp_AddEx::makeExpr(e, a, Mat(), s, 0);
    return e;
}
```

Once the `MatExpr` is returned, it will be converted to the correct type, and conversion from `float` to `uchar` gives values always in [0,255].

Since the conversion uses [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.3/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#saturate-cast), the values over 255 will always be saturated to 255.

You need to use a `CV_32FC1` or `CV_64FC1` matrix to get the "correct" values.

Comment: I don't understand details of conversion. And if result will be something >255 in float it converts to something random in range [0 255] or always to 255 in uchar?

Comment: @mrgloom, see updated answer. Always to 255, since the conversion will use saturate_cast